# xquery issue to get data from child nodes where matching value is found

Tags: xquery

I am facing an issue with Xquery.
Below is the example of xml on where I am applying xquery to get value of Price based on Author and year. However query is returning all values from Price tag.

Number of Book tags are not finite and can be from 1 to N.

XML:

```
<root>
<_1>
<book >
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2010</year>
  <price>60</price>
</book>
<book >
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2009</year>
  <price>50</price>
</book>
</_1>
</root>
```

XQuery:

```
for $record in /root/*
where  $record/book/year='2009' and $record/book/author='Vaidyanathan Nagarajan'
return 
fn:data($record/book/price)
```

Output:
60 50

Required output:
50

Thanks

Comment: Did you hand type this, or is the `<` missing in `/_1>` ?

Comment: please consider this as typing error... it is </_1>

Answer (score 0):

Your current XPath `/root/*` is matching `/root/_1`, and the where clause tests whether that `_1` element has a `book` element who's `year` is 2009 and that it has a `book` element who's author is Vaidyanathan Nagarajan. Note that there could be any book that satisfies either condition - it is not saying that there is a single book that passes both of those criteria. The where clause would eliminate `$record` items that don't satisfy the where clause criteria, not filter the `$record/book` elements. Then, you are returning both of the `book/price` values from the `/root/_1`.

If you only want the `price` from the `book` that satisfies both of the conditions in the where clause, then try this:

```
for $book in /root/*/book
where  $book/year='2009' and $book/author='Vaidyanathan Nagarajan'
return 
  fn:data($book/price)
```

You could also achieve the same thing without a FLWOR and just use an XPath with a predicate filter:

```
/root/*/book[year='2009' and author='Vaidyanathan Nagarajan']/price/fn:data()
```

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen, your alternate solution is actually what I had been looking for.  Thanks again!